# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. >

Tags: android

Tengo una app en Google Play la cual quería duplicar, modificar un par de cosas y subir como una app nueva, la intencion era tener una version gratuita (1) y una paga (2), así que cambié el Application ID e hice un nuevo certificado JKS y la subí sin problemas. Ahora cuando intento generar un apk firmado para la app original me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key KEYALIAS from store "D:\certificado_app.jks": Cannot recover key

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo guardados ambos jks con sus respectivos user y pass, pero solo puedo hacer APK firmados de la segunda version. Como dato adicional; ambos llevan el mismo alias.
No soy desarrollador, soy novato.

¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: "así que cambié el Application ID e hice un nuevo certificado JKS" en realidad si es la misma aplicación debes conservar el mismo ID, en cuanto a el archivo .jks no era necesario crear otro, me parece que este es el problema.

Comment: En teoría no es la misma app, le cambié el applicationId e hice un nuevo certificado JKS para poder subirlo como una aplicación distinta. Ambas apps son la misma pero una versión (gratuita) tiene contenido capado y la otra no (paga). Supongo que lo hice mal, no consigo recuperar la primera app.